# Calculate simple formula when multiple values in table meet criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating an excel template that needs to run a fairly simple formula based on the combination or VAR-1 and VAR-A

> 'PROD-1'+(('PROD-2'+'PROD-3')/1.7)

The raw data has some variability to it month-to-month which is where I'm stuck.

| VAR-1/2 | VAR-A/B/C | PROD-1/2/3 | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VAR-1 | VAR-A | PROD-1 | 211.9 |
| VAR-1 | VAR-A | PROD-2 | 5 |
| VAR-1 | VAR-A | PROD-3 | 36 |
| VAR-1 | VAR-B | PROD-1 | 33.6 |
| VAR-1 | VAR-B | PROD-2 | 164 |
| VAR-1 | VAR-C | PROD-1 | 8.6 |
| VAR-1 | VAR-C | PROD-3 | 23.7 |
| VAR-2 | VAR-A | PROD-1 | 82.7 |
| VAR-2 | VAR-A | PROD-2 | 6.3 |
| VAR-2 | VAR-B | PROD-1 | 176 |
| VAR-2 | VAR-B | PROD-3 | 5.3 |

In my table above, the result of the formula for VAR-1 & VAR-A would be 236 - `211.9+((5+36)/1.7)`

My issue is, because the data varies, for group of VAR-1 & VAR-B, I only have PROD-1 & PROD-2 - Thus my formula is now - `'PROD-1'+(('PROD-2')/1.7)` - `33.6+(164/1.7) = 130.1`

My question is, how do I create a formula to take this into account?
I'm wanting to report into a template similar to below, with a single cell containing the total for each combination of VAR-A/B/C & VAR-1/2

| Totals |  |
| --- | --- |
| Total VAR-A VAR-1 | *Formula* |
| Total VAR-A VAR-2 | *Formula* |
|  |  |
| Total VAR-B VAR-1 | *Formula* |
| Total VAR-B VAR-2 | *Formula* |
|  |  |
| Total VAR-C VAR-1 | *Formula* |
| Total VAR-C VAR-2 | *Formula* |

I think the formula needs to do some sort of index or hlookup to find each PROD value for the given combination of VAR-A/B/C & VAR-1/2 and place each PROD value in it's correct location in the formula - I just cannot work out how.

Comment: When `PROD-3` is missing add it as zero `0`. It will return the required value.

Comment: So your expected formula is `PROD-1 + SUM(PROD-2...PROD-n)/1.7` or do I misunderstand somthing? Which excel-version do you use?

Comment: That's close to what the formula needs to be, but PROD-2 and PROD-3 don't always exist in the monthly report. PROD-1 will always exist.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=$A15)*($B$2:$B$12=$B15)*($C$2:$C$12="PROD-1")*($D$2:$D$12))
+SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=$A15)*($B$2:$B$12=$B15)*($C$2:$C$12<>"PROD-1")*($D$2:$D$12))/1.7
```

These are basically two `SUMIFS`. The `PROD-1`-part can also be made dynamic. Let me know, if you neeed that.

[image]

Comment: How does this formula work? Is it expecting values in A15/B15 to apply against?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide all possible combinations of `VAR-1/2` and `VAR-A/B/C`.